# How to know if a Peano number is even

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

So I'm having a hard time trying with Peano and I need some help. I want to know if a Peano number is even and if yes then add:

```
0 + s(s(0)) = s(s(0))
0 + s(0) = No because one of the numbers odd
```

The code I have so far:

```
s(0).
s(X):- 
    X.

add(0,Y,Y).
add(s(X), Y, s(Z)):- 
    add(X,Y,Z).
```

Comment: Your `s/1` predicate is not necessary. It's a source of confusion for beginners that Prolog structures and Prolog predicates have the same shape, but they are not the same thing. For Peano numbers, you need `s/1` as a structure or functor, not as a predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not think about Peano numbers as numbers but as symbols.

Realize that the even Paeno numbers are `0` and a repeat of the pattern `s(s(X))` where `X` can be `0` or the pattern `s(s(X))`

Also I look at `0` and `s(0)` etc. as data, and you are using `s` as a predicate name. I am not saying it will not work this way, but that is not how I think about this.

The name of the predicate is `paeno_even` and it takes one argument.

The base case is

```
paeno_even(0).
```

next for recursive case

```
paeno_even(P)
```

and the processing on P just removes `s(s(X))` so do that in the head as

```
paeno_even(s(s(X)))
```

and then just do the recursive call

```
paeno_even(s(s(X))) :-
    paeno_even(X).
```

A few test to demonstrate:

```
?- paeno_even(0).
true.

?- paeno_even(s(0)).
false.

?- paeno_even(s(s(0))).
true.

?- paeno_even(s(s(s(0)))).
false.
```

The entire code as one snippet:

```
paeno_even(0).
paeno_even(s(s(X))) :-
    paeno_even(X).
```

Comment: I find i way to do it too, but yours is way better. I was substracting s(s(0)) to the number an call recursive to the function.